# Missing file in tensor package

Tags: c++, c, tensor

How to solve the problem of missing the config. h file in Itensor? This problem has caused the program to fail to run. We sincerely hope for your help.

Comment: Often, `config.h` is created by running a configuration script — it might be called `configure` or `Configure` (or possibly something else).  Sometimes, you have to create that configuration script from various bits and pieces.  You should have instructions on how to build the package — follow them.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this package https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source then you probably didn't run:

`./configure`